# What does "this " stand for here?

Tags: meaning

Try experimenting with working by a window or using full spectrum bulbs in your desk lamp. You will probably find that **this** improves the quality of your working environment.

"this " refers to "working by a window or using full spectrum bulbs in your desk lamp " or "experimenting" or "trying experimenting~"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This** refers to "working by a window or using full spectrum bulbs in your desk lamp ."

These sentences are suggesting that you conduct an experiment. As a result of your experiment, you will probably **find** that this improves the quality of your working environment.